# How to install a specific state of a linux os?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to back up a specific state of a linux OS so that when I install that specific image I'm right back where I left earlier?

Comment: Check out **Clonezilla**: https://clonezilla.org/

Comment: There are multiple projects to do this with and I have tried several of them in my opinion I would recommend backing up for config files and you can even create a simple text file of installed pacakges then when you reinstall you can have apt, yum, pacman whatever you use just simply read the packages from the file and install them.  With apt you can simple run `apt list --installed` for a complete list of installed packages.

Answer (score 2):

[Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) is like Microsoft Windows system restore, just make sure to include the home directory in the Users setting if you want to be able to restore files in Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc. [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) allows you to create a backup of your ENTIRE system and transfer it to another computer; I think via USB flash drive.